# CSS compiles the lighten( ) function and the similar SASS colors' functions in a way that does not seem right

Tags: sass

**CSS** compiles the following **mixin** code:

```
  @mixin message ($color, $background-color: lighten ($color, 20%) ) {
    color: $color;
    background-color: $background-color;
  }


  .message-danger { @include message(red); }
```

*to this*

```
.message-danger {
  color: red;
  background-color: lighten red, 20%; 
}
```

Obviously you can see that **CSS** did not compile the ***lighten( )*** function properly. I tried to change the color to a hex code color but that made no difference. I thought the problem was from my code editor, but when I tried the code on *sassmeister* it gave me the same result. Please help.

Comment: It's a typo. Just remove empty space beetween `lighten` & `(`

Comment: I think I need to change my glasses. Many thanks @ ReSedano .

Comment: You're welcome! :D